# Minecraft 1.8.9 Mob Rendering

Tags: java, render, minecraft

Can someone help me with my 1.8.9 Minecraft code for my mob? This is my ClientProxy.java for the mob render.

```
package com.goldenpie6.BobMod;

import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.Render;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.RenderManager;
import net.minecraft.entity.Entity;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.client.registry.IRenderFactory;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.client.registry.RenderingRegistry;

public class ClientProxy extends CommonProxy
{
    private Class<? extends Entity> Bob;
    private Class<Entity> c;

    @Override
    public void registerRendering()
    {
        RenderingRegistry.registerEntityRenderingHandler(c, new     IRenderFactory<Entity>()
                {

                    @Override
                    public Render<? super Entity>     createRenderFor(RenderManager manager) 
                    {
                        return null;
                    }

                }
        }
}
```

My Code won't work and I just need help making a mob as my friend asked me to make this mod for him.

Comment: What do you actually need help with? Whats the problem?

Comment: I keep getting errors